# Unexpected request: No more request expected, Jasmine Angular unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am working on a code that has some unit test failing which I am trying to run. The unit test is

```
        it('opens a confirmation dialog when deleting a layer and calls the delete wizard', function () {
            var numLayers = scope.service.layers.length;
            scope.deleteLayer({
                serviceName: 'service1',
                layerName: 'testLayer'
            });

            //Make sure confirmation dialog has been called
            expect(bootbox.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();

            //the layer is NOT removed from the list
           expect(scope.service.layers.length).toBe(numLayers);
            });
```

I keep getting the error:

> Unexpected request Get /api/configuration/utilities/userpreferences/f=json

I am trying to create a spyon for taking care of this api call. I am using this

```
spyOn(resourceFactory.configuration.utilities.userpreferences, 'get').and.callFake(function () { });
```

I have also defined this in the describe scope and injected in beforeeach

```
var resourceFactory = {
        configuration: {
            utilities: {
                userpreferences: {
                    get: function () { }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The thing is I dont care about this call to API since I am not testing it. 
When I use $httpBackend and do the following

```
/$httpBackend.whenGET("/api/configuration/utilities/userpreferences?f=json").respond({});
```

it works but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. Especially since its not used anywhere else in the project.

Can you help with this.